# grpc library versions in .net and java

Tags: java, .net, grpc, grpc-java

I am building a client for my GRPC api in Java and .net. I am looking to understand if there is any mapping between the java and .net libraries. I can see that google protobuf libraries match between the .net and java world. For example 3.19.x version is one of the most recent in both java and .net world.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java  &
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf/

Is there a similar relationship I need to be aware of when it comes to grpc libraries that are used. If I want to use an older version of the library then do the version in both .net and java have to match at some level? Any info on this will be helpful

java

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>1.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

.net

```
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.31.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.31.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Answer (score 0):

They should not need to match but, as with any dependencies, it's good to have a policy towards maintaining currency.

The SDKs provide the mechanism to get protobuf messages into and out of your application. The on-the-wire format should **not** change by SDK version.

The on-the-wire format **should** be defined by the `syntax` (currently [`proto3`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3)) defined in the protocol buffer definition (proto) files that are shared by the clients and servers that implement it.